# How to deploy an application [Looking for advice]

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, deployment

First, I don't know anything about deployment.
Here is my application :
I got a rest API backend using Spring Boot with a MongoDB using MongoLab. My frontend is built using React (webpack, cypress). 
I have this full application on gitlab in the same repo, with different folders (ie backend, frontend).
Where can I deploy this application? I guess I need to deploy separately those services. If you guys have any advice and give me some tutorials I could follow. What URL can I use like api.example.xx for back and example.xx for the front ?
Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad to get a summarised answer. I will give you a few hints that you can expand on.

For starters, since you do not know so much about deployment, I will recommend that you learn with a single machine than with multiple IP addresses. (no Docker, Kubernetes etc. just your applications on different ports)

### NOTE: below are the tools you will need to familiarise your self with before this attempt.

- linux terminal / GitBash for windows
- SSH (communication with your server)
- [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) (repository managament and versioning)
- [Github](https://github.com) / [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org)

#### Hosting services

Below are a few providers you can use to get you up and running although there are a turn other providers.

- [Linode hosting services](https://linode.com) - paid
- [Amazon Web services](https://linode.com) - paid/free
- [Netlify](https://netlify.com) - paid/free
- [Heroku](https://linode.com) - free

All these provide you with either a terminal or GUI to deploy/maintain your applications.

### Deployment

First, you will need to install all your application dependencies on the server of your choice. i.e. Databases (Mongo for your case) and other applications that support your app. (`The same way you did on your local machine`)

making sure that your project has the right configurations(passwords, reference URLs, etc.)

[See here on How to deploy your spring-boot application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mFcT2f8JJI)

In the meantime, you can try hosting your ReactApp on [Netlify](https://netlify.com) and see how it works

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll check out these hosting services, I think I'll deploy my backend on heroku and front on netlify :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you already have it in Gitlab right,And if you want an easy solution and a way out of deploying world then you might want to consider using [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

it makes deploying as easy as eating a piece of cake, just

1. Signup
2. Click on "New site from Git" Button
3. Select Gitlab in your case
4. Select the project you want to deploy and for netlify to install
5. It automatically detects build command and that's all, waits for your permission to build.
6. Once build is completed you can preview your application(there is a button for that in right corner) and then confirm your deployment.

*Plus it automatically deploys the changes in your git i.e pull requests,
you can choose whatever name you want your website to be(but should  be available)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think Netlify can't deploy any spring boot backend, so I'll just use netlify for hosting my frontend